# Почему value становится undefined

Tags: javascript, input

Подскажите пожалуйста. есть функция `CreateOL(number)` которая создает упорядоченный список, где в каждый `<li>` вложен `<input type="text">`
Имеется массив `<valspl>` в котором лежат текстовые элементы
Подразумевается, что пользователь вводит в input текст и потом нажав на кнопку `checkall` проверяет написанное с каждым элементом массива.
ОДНАКО при проверке в функции `checkTest()` на второй итерации отладчик отображает, что value undefined `(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined)`. Я пытался даже принудительно вписать значение в input `input.value ='123'` но все равно на второй итерации выбрасывает меня, говоря, что value undefined
вот код

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);
function CreateOL(number){
    this.myOL = document.createElement("ol");
    this.myOL.style.marginTop = "10px";
    this.myOL.style.marginLeft = "30px";
    let right = document.querySelector("#right");
     for (let i=1; i<=number; i++) {
        this.myLI = document.createElement("li");
            this.myInput = document.createElement("input");
            this.myInput.type = 'text';
            this.myInput.name = 'answerfield';
            this.myInput.size = '50';
            this.myInput.value = '123';
            this.myInput.className = 'inputanswer';
            this.myInput.style.border = "1px solid black";
            this.myLI.appendChild(this.myInput);
            this.myOL.appendChild(this.myLI);       
        }
     right.appendChild(this.myOL);
     } 
 
 var newsplit = localStorage.getItem("val_split");
 var newsplit = localStorage.getItem("val_split");
 var finalval = localStorage.getItem("key_val");
 let valspl = finalval.split('\n');
 
CreateOL(newsplit);


function checkText() {
    for (let i = 0; i < newsplit; i++) {
        let checkline = this.myOL.childNodes[i].childNodes[i].value; /*обращение к значение input*/
        if (valspl[i] == checkline) {alert("Получилось!!!");}
        else {alert("Работать!");}
            
    }
}

function init() {
        let btncheckall = document.getElementById("checkall");
        btncheckall.addEventListener("click", function() {
            checkText();
        });
}
```

Comment: где эта функция checkTest?

Comment: Ой туплю, checkText()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let checkline = this.myOL.childNodes[i].childNodes[0].value;
```

Comment: Вот же я разиня!!! Спасибо огромное